# How to mock @ngrx/store?

Tags: mocking, jasmine, rxjs, ngrx

I want to unit test a component. I am using @ngrx/store and rxjs in order to update my store from my component. To do that, I subscribe and unsubscribe to a store.
My unit test is failing with

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.store.unsubscribe') in config/spec-bundle.js

I am not able to find how to correctly mock my store and its event emitters.

Here are the following lines:

app.component.ts :

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe the observable
    this.userStore.unsubscribe();
  }
```

app.component.spec.ts :

how I mock the store :

```
        export class MockStore extends Subject<fromRoot.State> implements Store <fromRoot.State> {}
```

how I configure :

```
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            StoreModule.provideStore(reducer)
        ],
        declarations: [LoginComponent],
        providers: [
            BaseRequestOptions,
            MockBackend,
            { provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceStub },
            { provide: LoginService, useValue: loginServiceStub },
            { provide: LoggerService, useValue: loggerServiceStub },
            {
                provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: ConnectionBackend,
                    defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
                    return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
            },
            { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter }
        ]
  })
```

Tell me if you want more informations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's more than one way that you can mock the store and what you do is going to depend upon how you want to test.

When I mock the store in my tests, I'm only interested in two things:

- being able to easily emit a state that's relevant to the test; and
- being able to see any actions that are dispatched to the store during the test.the

I'm not interested in wiring up reducers, as they are tested elsewhere, so this is what I do.

I use a function like this to create a `Store` from two `Subject` instances:

```
import { Action, Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

export function mockStore<T>({
  actions = new Subject<Action>(),
  states = new Subject<T>()
}: {
  actions?: Subject<Action>,
  states?: Subject<T>
}): Store<T> {

  let result = states as any;
  result.dispatch = (action: Action) => actions.next(action);
  return result;
}
```

And in a `beforeEach` I create the `Store` and add it to the `TestBed`'s `providers`:

```
actions = new Subject<Action>();
states = new Subject<AppState>();
store = mockStore<AppState>({ actions, states });

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [EffectsTestingModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Store,
      useValue: store
    },
    ...
  ]
});
```

With the mocked `Store` injected in the components - or effects, or whatever you are testing - it's then simple to emit a particular state within a test - using the `states` subject - and it's easy to check to see that any expected actions have been dispatched - by subscribing to the `actions` subject.

Regarding your error, you should not be calling `unsubscribe` on the `Store`; you should call it on the [`Subscription`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html) object that's returned when you subscribe to the store - as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the way you do and still got the error ... As I said in the other answer, I already call my unsubscribe on the Subscription object.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be with your unsubscribe. You should be calling unsubscribe on your actually subscription instead of your observable/store.
eg. if you have subscription like this:

```
this.subscription = this._store
    .select('users')
    .subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
  });
```

you unsubscribe like this:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe the observable
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Also, not sure if you left out some code, but the way you mocked your store, it'd probably be sufficient to just use the actual store, and just spy on dispatch etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Some code was left out as my component and its test are really important. I have already unsubscribed as you describe in your comment, so I wonder my error is elsewhere ...

`this.userStore = this.store.let(fromRoot.get).subscribe((state: any) => { // navigates to welcome page if connection });`